# Semilattice of functions with meet as "common restriction"

Tags: reference-request, elementary-set-theory, functions

Is there an established name for the operator $\bigwedge$ which takes a nonempty family $F$ of functions and returns their "common restriction":
$$
\bigwedge F = f|_{\bigcap_{f_0, f_1 \in F}\operatorname{Eq}(f_0, f_1)}
$$

where $f$ is any element of $F$ and $\operatorname{Eq}$ is the *equalizer* operator, defined as
$$\operatorname{Eq}(f_0, f_1) = \{x \in \operatorname{dom}f_0 \cap \operatorname{dom}f_1\ |\ f_0(x) = f_1(x)\}.$$

I am looking for a journal reference on this operation. Perhaps it would be helpful to observe that one could form meet-semilattices of functions where $\bigwedge$ is the meet.